# How to install and run phileCMS?

Tags: php, content-management-system

Hey guys i just wanted to get this CMS , **[phileCMS](https://github.com/PhileCMS/Phile)**  up and running. So i just clone the project , made a folder phileCMS and pasted the files in there , now when i navigate to http://localhost/phileCMS/ , i see errors :

Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\phileCMS\lib\vendor\autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\phileCMS\lib\Phile\Bootstrap.php on line 105

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\phileCMS\lib\vendor\autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phileCMS\lib\Phile\Bootstrap.php on line 105

So , how do i get this thing running ?

i did see the installation guide **[HERE](https://github.com/PhileCMS/Phile#installation)** ,

But i still get the errors , so how do i set this thing up ?

Comment: It seems easier to set it up using composer, if you've cloned the project you either way need to do "composer install" in order to install the listed dependencies into the vendor folder. Composer will also create an autoload file in vendor/autoload

Comment: @JimL you are right !

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it does not work is because PhileCMS used to have the source version available as a download.
Before it could be used, however, you needed to run composer to install the dependencies.
Now, though, the download option is prepared and ready to use.

The best way to install PhileCMS is to use composer:

`composer create-project --no-dev phile-cms/phile`

That command should create a ready to go PhileCMS installation in a directory called 'phile'.

Or you can install it by downloading it: https://github.com/PhileCMS/Phile/releases/download/1.6.0/Phile.zip

Check out the docs:
https://github.com/PhileCMS/Phile/wiki/%5BHOW-TO%5D-Installation

Sorry about your bad experience, but I guess that's why they decided to prepare their download archive. :)

Comment: Thanks buddy will try it out , btw , moved on to bolt as found it a more practical alternative.

Comment: Bolt is nice. I was very tempted!

Comment: However, I just wanted to answer the question in case other people will wonder the same thing :)